# Producer/consumer Mesa vs Hoare semantics

Tags: c, synchronization, producer-consumer, monitors

I have come across two different implementations of monitors. One which uses a while loop that checks whether a particular condition is true each time before going to sleep and again when waking up from the sleep. The other just checks once whether the if condition is true and goes to sleep if it isn't but doesn't check again when woken up. I believe the former uses Mesa semantics and the latter uses Hoare semantics. The way Wikepedia implements the producer consumer problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem#Using_monitors) is using Mesa semantics I believe. How would we accomplish this using Hoare?

Would it be something like this?

```
monitor ProducerConsumer{
  int itemCount;
  int nextCount;
  condition full;
  condition empty;
  condition nextSem;

  init(n){
    itemCount = n;
  }

  void add(item){
    wait(mutex);
    if(itemCount == BUFFER_SIZE){
      cwait(full)
    }
    putItemIntoBuffer(item);
    itemCount = itemCount + 1;
    if(itemCount == 1){
      csignal(empty);
    }

    //To give priority to threads already in the monitor over
    //"normal" threads that want to enter the monitor for the 
    //first time.
    if(nextCount>0){
      signal(nextSem);
    }else{
      signal(mutex);
    }
  }

  void consume(){
    wait(mutex);
    if(itemCount == 0){
      cwait(empty);
    }
    item = removeItemFromBuffer();
    itemCount = itemCount - 1;
    if(itemcount == BUFFER_SIZE - 1 ){
      csignal(full);
    }

    //To give priority to threads already in the monitor over
    //"normal" threads that want to enter the monitor for the 
    //first time.
    if(nextCount>0){
      signal(nextSem);
    }else{
      signal(mutex);
    }
  }

  cwait(sem x){
    x.cnt = x.cnt + 1;
    if(nextCount > 0)
      signal(nextSem);
    else
      signal(mutex);
    endif
    wait(x);
    x.cnt = x.cnt - 1;
  }

  csignal(sem x){
    if(x.cnt > 1){
      nextCount = nextCount + 1;
      signal(x);
      wait(nextSem);
      nextCount = nextCount -1;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this

```
monitor ProducerConsumer{
    int BUFFERSIZE ; 
    int itemCount ; // invariant 0 _< itemCount and itemCount _< BUFFERSIZE
    condition notFull; // signalled only if itemCount < BUFFERSIZE
    condition notEmpty; // signalled only if itemCount > 0

    init(n){
        // Assumption. init is called once, before any call to add or remove.
        // precondition n >_ 1
        BUFFERZISE = n ;
        itemCount = 0;
    }

    void add(Item item){
        if(itemCount == BUFFER_SIZE){
            wait(notFull)
        }
        putItemIntoBuffer(item);
        itemCount = itemCount + 1;
        if( ! empty( notEmpty) ) signal(notEmpty);
    }

    Item consume(){
        if(itemCount == 0){
            wait( notEmpty );
        }
        Item item = removeItemFromBuffer();
        itemCount = itemCount - 1;
        if( ! empty(notFull) ) signal(notFull);
        return item ;
    }
}
```

I am assuming that, since this is a monitor, entering and leaving the monitor are implicit operations.

Note that, after the signal, there is no need for the thread to wait. If the language has a signalAndLeave operation, that could be used. For example, in Java, using my `monitor` package, you could end `add` with

```
if( ! notEmpty.isEmpty() ) notEmpty.signalAndLeave( ) ; else leave() ;
```

and you could end `remove` with

```
if( ! notFull.isEmpty() ) return notFull.signalAndLeave(item) else { leave() ; return item ; }
```